# How to shut down an iPad stuck on the Apple logo?

Tags: ipad, shutdown

Having an iPad stuck on the Apple logo, I cannot find a way to shut it down.

When holding down both the top "Power" button and the "Home" buttons, the iPad goes to black screen, but starts again even if I released the buttons when the screen went black.

So, the iPad always comes back to the state showing the back Apple logo on a white screen.

---

**Edit 1:**

Thank you for both answers until now.

- Holding only the power button down doesn't work in with this buggy iPad.
- Holding both the power and the home buttons down reboots the iPad; even if I release one or both buttons a fraction of a second after screen turns black, the screen always turns on in the next seconds

Comment: This iPad that doesn't boot correctly is one on which I attempt to do file recovery. For this reason, the recovery mode is not the solution, as I fear to loose pictures. 

I wanted to attempt the `Power+Volume up` procedure as a first step but this requires to turn the iPad off before.

Comment: When connecting the iPad to a Mac, iTunes detects the iPad, but cannot access its content because it is protected by a password. (I also hoped I could open the storage from the Disk Management, but it is NOT listed there as an external drive.) A PC on Windows sees the iPad as a 128GB external storage, and shows that about 40% is full, but I cannot access the files (despite the PC has HFS+ and APFS drivers). The "root" folder appears empty when opened in Windows file explorer.

Comment: Which model of iPad are you using?

Comment: Model A1566 (= iPad Air 2)

Answer (score 1):

Disconnect the iPad from the power supply if it's charging. Hold the power button and the home button at the same time until the screen gets black (takes about 3-5 seconds). Then release immediately. iPad should be turned off. If it's turning is back on again then either you were too slow releasing the buttons or something else is causing iPad to reboot.

In this case, the easiest way is to let it run out of battery.

Other options:
If you would like to fix the error, then connect iPad to iTunes and hold the power button and the home button until you see the iTunes logo. Then follow the instructions on iTunes.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but it did not work on the buggy iPad. I also tried connecting it to iTunes on a MacBook, but the iPad's storage is locked by its password. I cannot enter the password as the login mask never comes. See edit 1 in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Holding both buttons triggers your iPad to reboot. To turn off the iPad, hold the top or power button ONLY, until you see the 'slide to power off' image on the screen. Slide and the iPad will turn off.

The Apple Logo simply means the iPad is booting. Best to give it time to do so. If after considerable time (20+ mins) it still shows the logo, you can try to implement Recovery mode. You need a PC or Mac with iTunes installed, plus a Lightning cable.

Recovery Mode: Turn off the iPad.  Connect the iPad to the PC/Mac, Launch iTunes, and then hold down the Power and Home buttons until you see a "connect to iTunes" message on the iPad. This will allow you to restore the iPad, reinstalling the OS and apps.

Comment: Updated: holding both buttons is the problem

Comment: Thank you for your answer. By holding the power button only, there is no slide to power off. The iPad is in a buggy state where it cannot boot. The usual solution would be to reboot it is so called "safe mode", but I cannot turn it off. When running out of batteries, and then charging the iPad again, it automatically turns on when having enough charge. The purpose is data recovery and not reinstalling the iPad. I edited my original post with comments.